# Does `let` make a copy of the data?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

In my ViewModel I have this `LiveData` list:

```
val liveList: LiveData<List<Int>>
```

In my Activity, at some point I access the data in the list like this:

```
viewModel.liveList.value?.let { letList ->
    while (letList.size < 10)
        delay(100)
```

Some data gets added to `liveList` concurrently. (Above snippet doesn't run in the main thread). Will `letList` see these updates made to `liveList`? Thus, is `letList` still connected to `liveList`?

Or is `letList` a copy of the list in `liveList` made at the point in time the `let` is executed? Thus, if `liveList` happens to have less than 10 elements at this point, the `while` loop will never terminate, no matter how many elements are added to `liveList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will letList see these updates made to liveList?

Yes, it points to the same object.

> Thus, is letList still connected to liveList?

It's not really "connected".  It's just a reference to the same object.

> Or is letList a copy of the list in liveList made at the point in time the let is executed?

No, it is not a copy.

> Thus, if liveList happens to have less than 10 elements at this point, the while loop will never terminate, no matter how many elements are added to liveList?

That could be the case, since the contained list instance itself might have been replaced in the containing LiveData.  If the List instance is replaced with a new one inside the LiveData, and that list get changed over time, then the loop will never see a newly sized list since it will be stuck on the original.

Though I question if this is the best approach to the task at hand.  Maybe you should set up an observer on the list and do something whenever it's known to change, rather than busy-looping on it.

Comment: I think there is a mistake on the last quote, when you said "That looks to be the case." From the rest you said I think the opposite should be true. The `while` loop will terminate, when there are 10 or more elements added to `liveList`.

Comment: I think "busy-looping" isn't accurate word here. It is more like a polling, it consumes almost no resources.

Comment: Regardless, it is still an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) in modern programming.  You can likely do what you want reactively when the list is seen to change, not by checking in on it periodically in any circumstance.

Comment: Also I changed my answer a bit to account for the situation where the list inside the livedata is replaced with a new instance that becomes the new target of change.  In that case, your loop could get stuck on the original list.  LiveData ideally only should contain immutable objects, and you listen to changes by monitoring the livedata, not the held object.  In other words, don't change the list held by the livedata - instead replace it in the LiveData and let the observers on it know when it changed.

Comment: Bear in mind that unless you're using some form of synchronisation or similar, if the data gets updated in another thread, there's no guarantee that the waiting thread will see the update in a timely fashion — or in one go. (It's [entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) [possible](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html) to see a mixture of old and new data, leaving some parts invalid.) Multithreaded coding is counterintuitive and very tricky to get right…

Answer (score 0):

That code compiles to something like this (I'm going to use Kotlin syntax but you get the idea):

```
val letList = viewModel.liveList.value
if (letList != null) {
    while (letList.size < 10) {
        delay(100)
    }
}
```

so `letList` is a unique *variable* which is assigned the current value of `viewModel.liveList.value`. That's why running a `let` block on a nullable `var` is safe - even if the original var could be set to null by another thread, you're working with your own private copy assigned to the original value. You know it's not going to become null after it's been null-checked - in fact it's not going to change at all! Very useful for capturing that snapshot of a value

---

The other side to this is just what the value of that variable is - it's a reference to a `List` object. If something else has a reference to that same `List`, if it adds or removes some items, you'll see those changes too - because it's the same list you're both looking at

That's something you need to be careful about - you might want to create your own copy of that list so that this can't happen. You don't necessarily know how that `LiveData` is producing list values - is it creating a new `List` each time, so every list it pushes is independent? Or is it mutating a single list, and basically pushing the same object every time, acting as both "here's the current list" and "if you have a copy of that list from earlier, it just updated"?

Copying a list could be as simple as `theList.toList()`, but it'll be a different *`List` object* containing *the same item objects*. If those item objects can be mutated (e.g. if they have a `var` that can be changed) then wherever that object is referenced, even if it's in completely separate lists, that change will be visible. You have to know what you're working with and what guarantees it gives you